# Visa needed for Indian citizen to visit Zurich during layover?

Tags: schengen, transit, indian-citizens, switzerland

I am from India and travelling to Germany on a Schengen visa. On my way back to Mumbai from Munich, I have a layover of 9 hrs in Zurich. Can I travel in Zurich on the same documents or I need anything more?

Answer (score 6):

Switzerland – while not part of the European Union – belongs to the Schengen area so you don't need anything else than a Schengen visa. You won't even leave the Schengen area (or, in all likelihood, see any border guard) before leaving Zurich.

Answer (score 0):

You can, if your visa is valid for the Schengen zone and not just for Germany (it will say on the top of the visa).

If you have such a visa, you are free to travel within the Schengen zone (of which Switzerland is a member). Upon exit from Switzerland, your passport will be stamped as you will be leaving the Schengen area.

Comment: you have a spelling mistake "leaven".  (sorry, there is a ridiculous feature on this site where one can't make edits less than 6 characters)